# How to create a customizable environment that can be rapidly distributed to a local machine?

Tags: windows, docker, share, environment

I am looking for a way to be able to do the following:

- Create an instance of Windows with installed prerequisites and configuration
- An isolated environment would be recommended (As in it will not modify the existing configuration on local machine only in that VM-like environment)
- Ability to use the internet within that environment
- Using it sort of like a "check-point" (Start working on it, doing something wrong and being able to start once again from the instance that we created)
- Ability to share the environment
- Possibility of creating multiple different environments
- Low disk usage if possible
- Fast deployment of environment on local machine

I have looked into **Docker** which seems pretty good for what I need, but I want to investigate other options as well because it **requires Windows 10 x64 Enterprise**
.

**Something that works on Windows 7/Server/8/8.1 would be nice**

I would also love to get arguments on why X option is better than Y option.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Take a look at `Chef` also https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lS7xVHIl9zU

Comment: Vagrant boxes resolve this. You can build them with packer to simplify the states

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a completely separate environment, creating a Virtual Machine will be worth considering.

There are products from VMware and Oracle to create your virtual machine. I have been using **Oracle Virtualbox** (Oracle's virtual machine software) for some time now and find it pretty useful.

With a virtual machine it addresses all your concerns:

- **Create an instance of Windows with installed prerequisites and
  configuration** - A virtual machine will run on top of your installed OS without making
  any modifications in current installation
- **An isolated environment would be recommended (As in it will not
  modify the existing configuration on local machine only in that
  VM-like environment)** - It runs completely isolated like a separate
  machine.
- **Ability to use the internet within that environment** - You can use
  internet inside of a virtual machine
- **Using it sort of like a "check-point" (Start working on it, doing
  something wrong and being able to start once again from the instance
  that we created)** - You can take a snapshot and save the state. Next time when you start the VM it will be started from this state only.
- **Ability to share the environment** - Export a created VM and it can be
  reused.
- **Possibility of creating multiple different environments** - You can run
  multiple VMs on your machine. Configure the disk usage and RAM
  accordingly.
- **Low disk usage if possible** - Configurable while creating a virtual
  machine.
- **Fast deployment of environment on local machine** - Yes, you'll need
  the .iso image of your Operating System

Comment: Usually how large do .iso images of a windows machine get?

Comment: @SHPstr - The base image could be in the range of 2 GBs and it can extend up to multiple GBs based on what additional software you install in it.